# How to keep terraform DRY creating this repo structure?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-github

I am working on managing our GitHub org's repositories using terraform. I have one module that will be called for each repository I intend to manage (100+).

I currently have the following configuration:

```
terraform
  |-- modules
      |-- github
          |-- main.tf
          |-- variables.tf
  |-- repos
      |-- my_gh_repo
          |-- main.tf
      |-- my_gh_repo2
          |-- main.tf
```

My question is around managing the the backend and provider configurations for each of the repositories in the `repos` folder. I have experience with terragrunt and know how to craft a solution with that tool, but am seeing what I can do to **keep this purely terraform**.

The issue I have is that I would need to create a singular `backend.tf` and `providers.tf` that specifies my backend and github configuration for each repository folder, which is very messy. I'm unsure how to go about solving this so that I only need to specify the backend and provider **once** and have each repo inherit that configuration.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible with just Terraform. In Terraform's model, each separate configuration has an entirely-independent backend configuration. Any systematic rules you want to use for deciding those independent backend configurations would need to be implemented in _some_ surrounding automation helper, which could either be Terragrunt (as you mentioned) or a more specialized custom script that's focused only on specifying backend configurations.